# MongoDB grouping by array element

Tags: mongodb

I have data

```
{
    "_id" : 42,
    "status" : "active",
    "items" : [
        {
            "sku" : "00e8da9b",
            "qty" : 1,
            "item_details" : {
                "A" : 1,
                "B" : 2
            }
        },
        {
            "sku" : "0ab42f88",
            "qty" : 2,
            "item_details" : {
                "A" : 1,
                "B" : 3
            }
        },
        {
            "sku" : "0ab42f88",
            "qty" : 3,
            "item_details" : {
                "C" : 3,
                "D" : 4
            }
        },
        {
            "sku" : "0ab42f88",
            "qty" : 4,
            "item_details" : {
                "D" : 5,
                "E" : 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 43,
    "status" : "active",
    "items" : [
        {
            "sku" : "00e8da9b",
            "qty" : 1,
            "item_details" : {
                "A" : 1,
                "C" : 2
            }
        },
        {
            "sku" : "0ab42f88",
            "qty" : 4,
            "item_details" : {
                "D" : 2,
                "E" : 3
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to count sum of qty for every sku.

Comment: add some more details with proper text format

Answer (score 1):

In case you looking to get the sum of `qty` grouped by the `sku`, you can easily achieve that using aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: "$items"
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$items.sku",
        Count: {$sum: "$items.qty"}
      }
    }

  ]
);
```

The result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "00e8da9b", 
    "Count" : NumberInt(2)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "0ab42f88", 
    "Count" : NumberInt(13)
}
```